# JAVA: POST with credentials to REST endpoint

Tags: java, authentication, resttemplate

I used postman to do the following:

- POST request http://localhost:8082/login?username=john&password=abcd
- I then get a JSESSIONID

If I use postman to do post XML

- POST Body raw XML (text/xml) http://localhost:8082/api/method
- It does not work, unless I execute the previous post with the user name and password

Ok, so the above works in that order...How do I replicate this in Java?

I need to be able to POST to the login and then POST my XML to the API

I have tried this:

POST to login

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(message, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8082/login?username=john&password=abcd", request, String.class);
```

POST to Rest API

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(message, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8082/api/method", request, String.class);
```

But it seems as though they are separate requests. Still the login does not work either. Any help would be great thanks.

I don't mind using Apache HTTP client...

Comment: Send the session id in the second request in header or payload based on api specification?

Comment: Username and Passwords should really not be part of the url. Especially not in plaintext. I suggest you fix that before progressing further